# I can't call a class in subdirectory on Python

Tags: python, class, directory

I can't call a class in other class from a directory above.

I have a code with this directory hierarch:

```
main.py
|->classprimary.py
|->classec.py
|->classterc.py
```

In main.py, i call the classterc.py, bellow:

```
from lib.classprymary import A
from lib.classsec import B
from lib.classterc import C

var = C().list()
print(var)
```

This code work, when i move main.py to lib directory. But i like clean my code.

Comment: to clarify, when you say a "_directory above_" do you mean in a sub (child) directory or the parent directory ?

Comment: i have a main directory: workdir.
in workdir i have a file main.py and a subdir lib. In lib, i have the class classprumary,classsec...

Answer (score 0):

`import` in python allows to load modules.

To create a module you need to add a `__init__.py` file in your folder.

Should have this hierarchy

```
main.py
lib/
  __init__.py
  classprimary.py
  classec.py
  classterc.py
```

Comment: It's not strictly necessary (namespace packages, for example, don't require `__init__.py`). It all depends on how the code is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The directory structure defined in the question is like this:

```
main.py
lib/
  classprimary.py
  classec.py
  classterc.py
```

The call to the modules are correct.

```py
from lib.classprymary import A
from lib.classsec import B
from lib.classterc import C
```

Without knowing the structure of the calsses and functions inside the library, it appears as though one potential cause of error is from calling the class.

So `var = C().list()` should become `var = C.list()`.

Here is a good example with a commonly used moule:

```py
from datetime import datetime
t = datetime.now()
```

Note, in particular, how `datetime` does not require the parenthasis `( )` as it is not a method, whereas `now()` does.

However, if you do not notice this error when moving relative path then the cause could be as below.

The other part is that if you are moving `main.py` into the same directory as the modules, then the imports will change because the `lib` part of the import is no longer required if the *relative* path has changed:

```py
from classprymary import A
from classsec import B
from classterc import C
```

Comment: What is diference betwen C().list() and C.list(), when could i use them.

Comment: in very simple terms, the first one `C()` tries to *execute the function* block of code whereas the second one `C` is a *reference to the function* memory address. The question wants to refer to `C` and call `list()`, but is not doing this.  If the above is helpful, please do upvote and mark as accepted as it helps other stack users.